# Issue when calling an application from webApp

Tags: iphone, web-applications, launch

I Create a web application that when I click on button this open another application installed on iphone.
I call another application with this code:

```
window.launchAPP = function() 
   {
       setTimeout(function() 
       {
           window.location = 'http://www.app.com/'
       }, 500);
       window.location = 'app://';   
   };
```

This work fine if my webapp is called from safari. If I call webapp from my menu, after "add to home screen", other application is not called and I have this error message: "cannot open app. App could  not be opened. the error was the url can't be shown:".

Where is my mistake???

Answer (score 1):

[Launching Your Own Application via a Custom URL Scheme](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Like in android the best choice is registering  your custom URL Scheme.